# Do I need to reformat the hard drive when updating a Mac?

Tags: mac, macos

Do I need to reformat the hard drive when upgrading from OS X Mavericks to OS X El Capitan?

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to reformat your drive unless you want to do a fresh install.  You can upgrade in place without having to format.  If you find you are having problems after the upgrade, you can then reformat and start from scratch.

However, if you do reformat, ensure all of your documents and programs are backed up so you can restore them as it will wipe all data.

Answer (score 1):

If you proceed with the update procedure that Apple Store provide you, there is no necessity to erase your driver.

Indeed, all the content of your drive will remain and the only thing that will change will be the operative system that will be update.

In [this page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201541), you can find instruction to proceed with the update of your Mac device.